# Gap correction between two curves

Tags: area, curves, standard-error

I have two curves like this :

[image]

I would like to be able to calculate the gap between these two curves according to the Y value.

For example:

- In my example Y < 5, error between the two curves is almost 0%
- But for Y=7 blue is 5% greater
- For Y=10 blue is 15% greater
- etc.

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: $(y_1-y_2)^2$.... no?

Comment: This is the formula to measure distance between the two Y, right?

Comment: Oh yes, there are hundreds of ways to measure how two functions are close one each other. If you make $\frac 1 n \sum_i (y_1_i-y_2_i)^2$ you are evaluating how separated are those.

Comment: A percentage will be bad because it turns infinity for values oscilating close to zero.